# In Webpack, how do I expose vendor JS?

Tags: javascript, webpack, aem

Outside of Webpack, I have compiled and minified custom modules and vendor modules together. The result is a JS file that is basically a concatenation of the separate JS files. If I use a third-party vendor plug-in like [autoComplete.js](https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/), I can access its functions in the console by typing "autocomplete," which renders the function object. The same applies to other vendor modules as well.

If I use Webpack to compile modules, I can't access the autoComplete function in the console as before. How can I expose JS in this way so its functions are accessible? If I look at the rendered JS from Webpack, I can't even find a function named autoComplete.

I have a main.ts file I am using as the entry to import the Sass and JS. The JS files are placed in their own src folder. I have attempted adjusting some of the module.exports settings in the config but I'm not sure how to tell Webpack to bundle these in a way that exposes the functions globally like the non-Webpack build.

Comment: Why? All you've done is create a file that needs to be completely redownloaded if even a single letter in any of your vendor dependencies change. If they're not code that needs to be bundled in, just stick them in your asset dir and load them the normal way, so the browser can cache each file separate, the way browsers are supposed to work?

Comment: @Mike, if I'm building a framework like Bootstrap with a large collection of modules--both custom and vendor--I want them in one JS file just as Bootstrap has done: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Comment: And every single-letter change to that bundle will invalidate the entire bundle, so I hope you pause for a moment and ask yourself why that would make sense for _third party_ modules. Bootstrap's bundle is its own code, not third party libraries, so every change, by definition, is a new release, and thus a new bundle. Bundling your own code: perfectly sensible. Bundling third party vendor code: not so much.

Comment: @mike This is how we have compiled our framework JS for over a decade using the concatenation method I described above. A new version may include a newer custom module or an upgraded vendor module but nothing is invalidated by a version change.

Comment: Do you mean that you just want to *minify* JavaScript code (which itself makes use of globals), without *bundling* it into modules?  Webpack may simply be the wrong tool for that.

Comment: If you don't use the code, the [tree shaker](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) will remove it.

Comment: @david That could be what I mean, if I understand it correctly. The problem I have is that I need to use our former approach to build out JS in a similar way because we have moved our source code into a system that uses Webpack.

Comment: @user1138: If that former approach was just minifying then why can't you use whatever you were using before?  Webpack is specifically for bundling modules, which sounds like the wrong tool in this case.  The decision to use Webpack and the decision to only want minification without bundling appear to be conflicting decisions.

Comment: @david I agree. Is there no way to make it use a simpler approach at least for this? We want to move our frontend codebase into this big software suite (AEM ui.frontend), and that is its buildtool.

Comment: @user1138: I'm not aware of such a configuration in Webpack.  It may indeed not exist simply because minification by itself is already something other tools do.  If the team really wants to use Webpack then probably the ideal path forward would be to re-work the code so that it doesn't rely on global scope and can instead be bundled as modules.  But that's purely theoretical, knowing nothing about the code.  It'a also possible, though not generally recommended, to explicitly attach properties to `window` within your modules so those properties would be in global scope.

Comment: @david Thanks. I'll keep digging to see what alternatives there are. I suspect there is a way in the new ecosystem we have; I will just need to find out what their approach is. Once I do, I'll come back and update this question--if it is still here.